# How to make i18next work on cordova ios-6?

Tags: cordova, i18next

I have an issue with i18next (old version, not the current one), which I used for years for translation with PhoneGap. I'm now compiling with Volt Builder.

It seems that it does not work with newer iOS.
I’ve tried plugins such as cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr and cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, but it is still not working.

Also tried :

```
<plugin name="@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr" />
```

with :

```
        <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
        <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
        <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
        <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

(as found in [i18next doesn't translate on Cordova iOS 6.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919545/i18next-doesnt-translate-on-cordova-ios-6-1-0))

with and without CDVWKWebViewEngine:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /></feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
```

My CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:; prefetch-src 'self';">`
```

And the kind of error I see in Inspect:

```
/www/appname.de.json:1 OPTIONS file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/CE6EDA78-1B4A-4B13-9293-92B9495532F1/appname.app/www/translation.de.json
    index.html:595 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/CE6EDA78-1B4A-4B13-9293-92B9495532F1/appname.app/www/translation.de.json. Preflight response is not successful
```

It is really frustrating, hour after hour of trying stuff, so I’d appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this

```
<plugin name="@ahovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix" />
<platform name="ios">
 <feature name="CDVWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWebViewEngine" />
 </feature>
</platform>
```